# JS: Javascript validation not working

Tags: javascript

[Here is js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/55qgqhvz/)

I have done many validation but this time not working i dont know how please help me..
**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" name="contactformm" onsubmit="return valiadd()">
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-sm-4'>
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='fname'>Name</label>
                                <input type='text' name='namee' class='form-control' />
                            </div>

                            <div class='text-right'>
                                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Submit' />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

**Javascript code**

```
function valiadd {
var name = document.contactformm.namee.value;
     if(name==""){
         alert('Please Fill Your Name');
         document.contactformm.namee.focus();
         return false;
     }

     else {
        return true;
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the parentheses in the function, Use the chrome console to detect errors

```
function valiadd (){
var name = document.contactformm.namee.value;
     if(name==""){
         alert('Please Fill Your Name');
         document.contactformm.namee.focus();
         return false;
     }
        return true;        
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you just forgot to add brackets after your function name

just change this line :

```
function valiadd {
```

with

```
function valiadd() {
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't put braces after function name.

Working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/55qgqhvz/1/

```
function valiadd() {
 var name = document.contactformm.namee.value;
 if(name==""){
     alert('Please Fill Your Name');
     document.contactformm.namee.focus();
     return false;
 }

 else {
    return true;
 }

}
```